# Batch file to open server with port

Tags: batch-file, port

I am trying to write a script to connect to a server on a specific port. I can get the script to open the browser with the server address as long as I don't include the port. If I try to include the port then I get an error saying:

> There is no program associated to perform the requested action...

When I exclude the port it attempts to connect to the server in the browser, but this won't work without a port. Here's some of my code:

```
@ECHO off

SET serv=exampleserver.company.com

ECHO Server address is %serv%   

SET /p port=Enter the port number 

ECHO The port is %port%

SET addr=www.%serv%

ECHO Your full address is %addr%:%port%

START %addr%:%port%

PAUSE
EXIT
```

Comment: Try surrounding the parameter to the start command in quotes. `START "%addr%:%port%"`

Comment: I think you need an `http://` prefix so the START to recognize it need to open the browser

Answer (score 2):

as you can test manually, while `start www.stackoverflow.com` will work, `start stackoverflow.com` won't, and neither `start www.stackoverflow.com:80`. I suspect that the recognition of "www." is a especially encoded exception.
To resolve this, use `start http://<server>:<port>`.

as an aside, if you surround your start parameter with quotes (required if it has a space or other separator), you need to put (empty) quotes before, like `start "" "c:\program files\bla"`, since the first quoted argument will be interpreted as a window title.

xyz:abc is actually a valid filename under windows, where the second part names an alternate data stream (ADS).